# pygame/sprites: mob collision

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Hi I recently started to get into the pygame library and making some small projects. I'm making just a very simple game in which you as a player have to dodge the enemies. However, I want to delete the mobs when they collide with each other. I thought of the following code, however, it only removes one of the mobs. The mobs are in both all_sprites, and in mob_sprites. I'm very new on sprites and pygame, so there probably is a silly mistake inhere, hopefully someone can help me.

```
# check mob collision
for mob in mobs:
    temp_sprites.add(mob)
    mobs.remove(mob)
    collision = pg.sprite.groupcollide(temp_sprites, mobs, True, True)
    for col in collision:
        # score is just for the game
        score += col.size
    else:
        mobs.add(mob)
        all_sprites.add(mob)

    temp_sprites.remove(mob)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you use a `for...else` loop; and the `else` part will be executed if you don't `break` the for loop in case of a collision, and thus re-adding the sprite.

The second problem with your code is that while `groupcollide` will correctly remove the sprites from their groups, they will be readded since they are still stored in the list you're iterating over with your `for` loop (iterating over a sprite group will create a new list every time).

So you can either fix your code with something like this:

```
    for mob in mobs.sprites():
        
        if not mob.groups():
            # mob was already removed by a previous iteration of this loop
            continue

        temp_sprites.add(mob)
        mobs.remove(mob)
        collision = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(temp_sprites, mobs, True, True)
        for col in collision:
            # score is just for the game
            score += col.size
            break
        else:
            mobs.add(mob)
            all_sprites.add(mob)

        temp_sprites.remove(mob)
```

but I would suggest to handle the collision in the `update` method of the sprite instead.

```
def update(self):
    # whatever
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.mobs, True, collide_rect_not_self):
        self.kill()
```

where `self.mobs` is a reference to the `mobs` group and `collide_rect_not_self` is a simple wrapper around `pygame.sprite.collide_rect`:

```
def collide_rect_not_self(a, b):
    if a != b:
        return pygame.sprite.collide_rect(a, b)
```

Here's a full example:

```
import random
import pygame

def collide_rect_not_self(a, b):
    if a != b:
        return pygame.sprite.collide_rect(a, b)

class Actor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, mobs, static, *grps):
        super().__init__(mobs, *grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(*pos)
        self.vel = pygame.Vector2(random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)) if not static else pygame.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.mobs = mobs

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        if not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().contains(self.rect):
            self.vel *= -1
            self.rect.clamp_ip(pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect())
            self.pos = self.rect.center
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.mobs, True, collide_rect_not_self):
            self.kill()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                Actor(event.pos, mobs, event.button == 1, all_sprites)
                    
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        all_sprites.update()
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        clock.tick(30)
        
               
        pygame.display.flip()
main()
```

Use the left mouse button to place a static rect and the other mouse buttons to place a moving one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to destroy a sprite, then it is sufficient to invoke [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill):

```py
mob.kill()
```

`kill` removes the Sprite from all the Groups that contain it.

If you want to detect if a sprite collides with any other sprite in a loop, then I recommend to use 2 nested loops and [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide):

For instance:

```py
for mob1 in mobs:
    for mob2 in mobs:
        
        if mob1 != mob2 and pg.sprite.collide_rect(mob1, mob2):
            mob1.kill()
            mob2.kill()

            # score is just for the game
            score += col.size
```